# Docker mongodb 4.2 not running with bind mount

Tags: json, mongodb, docker

I'm learning docker and mongodb at the same time, I'm trying to import a collection with a JSON file in a docker container but there is an issue, as this is a container I'm using bind mounts to refer this JSON from my local machine to my container but if I run it with bind mounts mongodb won't run.

I'm using the following command to run just the container using bash:

```
sudo docker exec -it mongo-image bash
```

inside the container I just write `mongo` and terminal from mongo works as expected, if I run the following command:

```
sudo docker run -it -v "$(pwd)":/MyData mongo:4.2 /bin/bash
```

I see the files from my local machine but If I type `mongo` terminal won't let me start

```
root@e753483bb65b:/# mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.15
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2021-07-30T21:05:14.037+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 
127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 
127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:353:17
@(connect):2:6
2021-07-30T21:05:14.040+0000 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2021-07-30T21:05:14.040+0000 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

Is there any suggestion that you could give me to import a json file collection to mongo db docker container or fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overwriting the default run command of mongo and it has nothing to do with mounting and volumes. I suggest you change this:

```
sudo docker run -it -v "$(pwd)":/MyData mongo:4.2 /bin/bash
```

in two separate commands:

```
sudo docker run -d -v "$(pwd)":/MyData mongo:4.2
```

and then when it printed the id of the running container, create an interactive shell:

```
sudo docker exec -it fb82f /bin/bash
```

where fb82f is the initial characters of the docker container.